# Blender 2.8: I want to select the whole image for each face of a cube

Tags: uv-image-editor

I am super new to Blender and I am having trouble with there being a lot of information on the web that does not apply to 2.8. I am hoping this will be simple.

Here is my cube and my texture:
[image]

See the little orange square that shows what portion of my texture is on my cube face? How do I make that the whole texture and not just that little part? I tried hilighting the vertexes and dragging them to the corners, but I cannot seem to be precise enough, I end up with corners that are slightly off... There must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want would be to go into **Edit Mode**, select all, press the <kbd>U</kbd> key and then select **Cube Projection**.

[image]

This will unwrap your cube and overlay all faces on top of each other, completely filling the UV texture space.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! That is perfect for my needs! Even the rotation is spot on! Thank you so much!